# JavaScript: сортировка объекта по определенному порадку ключей

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть объект: `var data =  {surname: "Ivanov", name: "Pavel", profile: "12", additional: "18 y.o."};`

Как отсортировать объект таким образом, чтобы не зависимо от количества ключей и значений, на первом месте в объекте стоял ключ `name`, затем `surname`, потом `additional` и т.д.

Т.е. чтобы порядок в объекте всегда был таким:

```
var data =  {name: "Pavel", surname: "Ivanov", additional: "18 y.o.", profile: "12"};
```

Спасибо!

Comment: А что значит: "Порядок в объекте" ?

Comment: @Чад чтобы на первом месте стоял name, затем surname, потом additional и т.д. Чтобы при переборе этого объекта в консоли вывелись значения в упомянутом мной порядке.